# “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError : unable to create new native Thread”

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, out-of-memory, activemq-classic

I am getting this error while I am trying to post some messages into a queue using JMSTemplate.

I am trying to push more than 10000 messages in queue using for loop and I get this error.

I have limit of 4096 threads on my system.

In the threadDumps I can see  below thread mostly.

```
"SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-36991" prio=10 tid=0x00007f857dc13000 nid=0x5a9 waiting on condition [0x00007f83f21e9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000748860208> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.take(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:374)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.FutureResponse.getResult(FutureResponse.java:40)
    at org.apache.activemq.transport.ResponseCorrelator.request(ResponseCorrelator.java:87)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQConnection.java:1394)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.syncSendPacket(ActiveMQSession.java:1925)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.<init>(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:125)
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.createProducer(ActiveMQSession.java:969)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.getMessageProducer(PooledSession.java:395)
    at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.createProducer(PooledSession.java:359)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doCreateProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.createProducer(JmsTemplate.java:1025)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:598)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$3.doInJms(JmsTemplate.java:569)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:491)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:566)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:646)
    at com.jato.frameworks.commons.util.JATOJMSProducer.sendMessageToQueue(JATOJMSProducer.java:59)
```

What I suspect is the threads which are created to post a message in the queue are getting created more rapidly than the rate they are being killed.

Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Is that thread dump the stack trace of the `OutOfMemoryError` you mentioned in the title?

Comment: Ditto what dorukayhan said:  Please post the exception stack trace instead of some other, random stack.  If the exception was not thrown from within code that you wrote, then this may not be the appropriate forum for your question.

Comment: @dorukayhan  Out of memory error is the one which i mentioned in the title.  However i tried to find the root cause, I saw the threaddumps and I can see the given thread mostly. I am trying to understand if there is any property where the rate at which i am posting message to queue do not create a new thread everytime.